# Is it possible to use MaterialStatesController in different InkWell's statesController?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, flutter-animation

The problem is that when one of the inkwell is pressed, the other does not change its state.

Interactive example: https://dartpad.dev/?id=cd60f05128d673eb8625b4dc1885cd91

I need 2 inkwell to work as one. When you pressed circle, bar will pressed too, when you left circle, bar will change state to empty too. And vice versa.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution is to replace Inkwells with AnimatedContainer and check with GestureDetector whenever onTapDown and onTapUp, and change color of AnimatedContainer. Simple example: https://dartpad.dev/?id=551b0ffbd3d15352d89748329d3bd135

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).